# Issues sending Latin accented characters (ã,õ,á,é,í,…) to a database table in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, query

I am having problems making mydatabase table show Latin caracters. (ã,õ,á,é,í,…). I am using  WAMP server with Apache 2.4.9 and MySQL 5.6.17.

I have a simple form that I created in HTML and I have a PHP code witch runs a query and creates the account. Here is the PHP code:

```
include('config.php'); //My database data for connection

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO account SET username = '".$username."', password = PASSWORD('".$password."'), email = '".$email."'";
    $execute_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($execute_query) { 
        //Creates the account
    }
    else { 
        //If an error occures
    }
}
```

Now for example, I create an account with:

```
Username: Luís
Password: 1234
E-mail: somemail@mail.com
```

When I go check the Table it shows the account created but the username shows **LuÃs** instead of **Luís**.

*Things I have tried:*

```
Creating a DataBase and Table with:
utf8_general_ci
utf8_unicode_ci
utf8mb4_general_ci
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
latin1_swedish_ci
```

None of them worked, it always shows that **Ã** instead of **í**.

Answer (score 3):

#### I have fixed my problem with the query "SET NAMES utf8".

```
include('config.php'); //My Database data for connection.
//Connection set with $connection = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db)

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $connection->query("SET NAMES utf8"); //FIXED (Gets $connection from config.php and runs the query "SET NAMES utf8")
    $query = "INSERT INTO account SET username = '".$username."', password = PASSWORD('".$password."'), email = '".$email."'";
    $execute_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($execute_query) { 
        //Creates the account
    }
    else { 
        //If an error occures
    }
}
```

Thank you [@Giacomo1968 for trying to help me in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/978207/167207), after all I had no problems with my database table.

My database and table were set with `CHARSET=utf8` and `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`.